# Magento 1.9.x.x remove "freeshipping" option conditionally from checkout quote without editing any ".phtml" templates

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, event-observer, onestepcheckout, free-shipping

Just need as I asked in the main question title.

Right now I have created the below function in my observer which executes on event `sales_quote_collect_totals_before`, with below code:

```
public function validateFreeShipping(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    //$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setFreeShipping($setFreeShipping);
    $quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
    $setFreeShipping = true;
    foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem) {
        $itemSku = $quoteItem->getSku();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $itemSku);
        $prodCatIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    }
    # echo "<pre/>";print_r($prodCatIds);
    foreach ($prodCatIds as $catId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
        $allowFreeshipping = $category->getAllowFreeshipping();
        if($allowFreeshipping == "194") $setFreeShipping = false;
    }
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setFreeShipping($setFreeShipping);
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
}
```

But this never seems to work, and I always get "Free Shipping" method enabled no matter what.

Can anyone suggest a standard way to do this which involves event catching observers ?

Answer (score 0):

There is one event `payment_method_is_active` for payment method filtration. We don’t have similar event: `shipping_method_is_active` available for shipping method.

But You can  filter by overriding `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectCarrierRates()`.

**Step 1:**
Create a file `Mageweb_ShippingFilter.xml` in `app > etc > modules` and paste below code in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
      <modules>
         <Mageweb_ShippingFilter>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
         </Mageweb_ShippingFilter>
      </modules>
   </config>
```

**Step 2:** Create `Data.php` file in `app >  code > community > Mageweb > ShippingFilter > Helper` and paste below code.

```
<?php
class Mageweb_ShippingFilter_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**Step 3:** Create `Shipping.php` file in `app >  code > community > Mageweb > ShippingFilter > Model > Shipping` and paste below code.

```
<?php 
class Mageweb_ShippingFilter_Model_Shipping_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
{
// here you can add code
public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
{
    if (!$this->_checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request)) {
        return $this;
    }
    return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
}

protected function _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request = null)
{
    $isLoggedIn  = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
    if(!$isLoggedIn){
        if($carrierCode == 'flatrate'){ #Hide Flat Rate for non logged in customers
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**Step 4:** **Step 3:** Create `config.xml` file in `app >  code > community > Mageweb > ShippingFilter > etc` and paste below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <Mageweb_ShippingFilter>
         <version>0.1.0</version>
      </Mageweb_ShippingFilter>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <helpers>
          <shippingfilter>
             <class>Mageweb_ShippingFilter_Helper</class>
          </shippingfilter>
       </helpers>
       <models>
          <shippingfilter>
             <class>Mageweb_ShippingFilter_Model</class>
             <resourceModel>shippingfilter_mysql4</resourceModel>
          </shippingfilter>
          <shipping>
            <rewrite>
                <shipping>Mageweb_ShippingFilter_Model_Shipping_Shipping</shipping>
            </rewrite>
         </shipping>
      </models>
   </global>
</config>
```

You can add/edit code in `Mageweb_ShippingFilter_Model_Shipping_Shipping` file.